# Libreria APACHE POI lee celdas con el valor NULL

Tags: java-8, librería, apache-poi

estoy haciendo la parte sintáctica de un compilador en Java, para ello necesito de una matriz que tengo en Excel, esta matriz la cargo en un arreglo con la librería Apache POI, tengo el problema que solo esta guardando los datos de 10 filas, mientras que todo lo demás lo marca como NULL, mi matriz es de 51x85 por y esta sujeta a cambios por lo que me es muy importante que se lea con código, porque la información es mucha, espero se me pueda ayudar.

```
 public void cargarMatrizSint(){
    matrizSint=new String[51][85];
    
        
     try {
         FileInputStream arch;
         arch = new FileInputStream("matrizSint.xlsx");
         XSSFWorkbook book= new XSSFWorkbook(arch);
         XSSFSheet hoja=book.getSheetAt(0);
         
         int nFilas=hoja.getLastRowNum();
         System.out.println("Numero de filas: "+nFilas);
         
         for (int i = 0; i < nFilas; i++) {
             Row fila=hoja.getRow(i);
            try{
                int nColumnas=fila.getLastCellNum();
                System.out.println("Numero de columnas: "+nColumnas);
            
                for (int j = 0; j < nColumnas; j++) {
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell celda=fila.getCell(j);
                    matrizSint[i][j]=fila.getCell(j).toString();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                break;
            }
            
         }
         
         
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema. El `break` dentro del catch estaba demás.

Lo quité y se solucionó.